# Skipping a review, with an option to follow up and learn how I *should* have reviewed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues

I have just started to go through the queues for first posts, late answers & triage and since I'm new to it I'm struggling to pick the right option for some question.

I wish there was an option: "Do nothing, but follow how a more experienced user handles it" so that I pass on the question, but I can still learn what the right answer would have been. Now I just skip and still don't know what to do when I see a similar question next time.

Is there any way to do this? If not, I suggest that there should be such a feature.

Comment: There's no such option. You can bookmark them and visit them later. Or go to your review overview later and check "show skipped reviews". Although tbh, more experienced reviewers get it wrong often enough, too.

Comment: Actually a pretty neat idea I think, but not possible at the moment

Comment: That would be a really great feature.

Comment: I agree this would be a nice feature, maybe get a notification with a link to the review so you could see the final result would be nice!

Comment: Cross site dupe with a user script to do what you want: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248338/adding-the-consensus-to-reviews-history

Comment: I usually leave the tab/window open for awhile (at least a good half hour), then go back through my history to see how other people voted.

Comment: meta-meta suggestion: review the reviews reviewers have made. then review the reviews of the reviews reviewers have made.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is an option to see your review history [including skipped reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234909/165773).

For first posts the link looks like as follows: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history?skipped=true

For late answers and triage (and more generally for all other kinds of reviews) URLs look similar:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/history?skipped=true

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history?skipped=true

Worth noting that for 10K users links like these would show more: they will additionally see reviews done (not skipped) by other users.

Comment: Yeah, using this for this purpose as someone with more than 10k rep is rather pointless. It shows me all reviews done by all users and my own reviews while also including my skipped reviews. To get just a list of my own skipped reviews I have to append `&userId=4639281` to the URL. Still, it would be nice to be able to see _just_ one given result.

Comment: neat trick with that `&userId` @TinyGiant - I didn't know about it. Will use it at the site where I have 10K